# List of List not rendering properly in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've got the following data model I want to render in a SwiftUI app on MacOS:

```
class Level2 : Identifiable {
    var content2 : String
    init(content2: String) {
        self.content2 = content2
    }
}

@Observable
class Level1: Identifiable {
    var content1 : String
    var arrayOf2 : [Level2] = []
    init(content1: String, arrayOf2: [Level2]) {
        self.content1 = content1
        self.arrayOf2 = arrayOf2
    }
}

@Observable
class DataModel {
    var arrayOf1 : [Level1]

    init() {
        arrayOf1 = [
            Level1(content1: "Hello 1", arrayOf2: []),
            Level1(content1: "Hello 2", arrayOf2: [
                Level2(content2: "2.1"),
                Level2(content2: "2.2"),
                Level2(content2: "2.3")
            ]),
            Level1(content1: "Hello 3", arrayOf2: [
                Level2(content2: "3.1"),
                Level2(content2: "3.2"),
                Level2(content2: "3.3")
            ]),
            Level1(content1: "Hello 4", arrayOf2: []),
            Level1(content1: "Hello 5", arrayOf2: [
                Level2(content2: "5.1"),
                Level2(content2: "5.2"),
                Level2(content2: "5.3")
            ])
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to setup a ContentView using a List for the first level of elements which contains another list for the second level of elements:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var dataModel = DataModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(dataModel.arrayOf1) { level1Element in
                Text(level1Element.content1)
                List(level1Element.arrayOf2) {
                    element2 in Text(element2.content2)
                        .frame(width: 120)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

It doesn't render as expect.
I've got this:

[image]

But I was expecting this:

[image]

If I change `List(level1Element.arrayOf2)` By `ForEach(level1Element.arrayOf2)`, I've got the expected result.

Is there a limitation with List containers? Isn't it possible to have List of List?

I'm using XCode 15.1. Swift version is 5.9

Comment: "Isn't it possible to have List of List?" No. Is that all you are asking? If `ForEach` works for you, just use that.

Comment: Try DisclosureGroup or switch the second List to ForEach and adjust the row padding